# Deleting items from JQuery based only shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to build a JQuery shopping cart just for exercise and learning propuse.
But i have a problem with coding the option to delete items from the shopping cart.
Here is the code:

```
<script src="assets/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sum=0;
    var num=1;
    $(function() {          
        //Assign the producets a price date
        $( "#Product1" ).data( "price", 400 );
        $( "#Product2" ).data( "price", 500 );
        $( "#Product3" ).data( "price", 600 );

        //Adding the requested producted to the shopping cart
        $(".buy").on("click",function(evt) {
            var id=$(this).attr("id");
            $("#shopping_cart_items").append($(this).attr( "id" ) + " " +  "price: ");
            $("#shopping_cart_items").append($(this).data( "price" ) + "$" + "<img src='assets/x.png' width='10px' height='10px' class='cancel' id="
            +id + " + data-num= "+ num++ + " + >" + "<br>");

            //summing up the overall price
            sum=sum+$(this).data( "price" );
            $("#sum").text(sum+ "$");

            //Delete product from the shopping cart
            $(".cancel").on("click",function(evt) {
                //?
            }); 
        });
    });

</script>
<style>
#product img{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;   
}
#product{
    float: left;
    padding:5px;    
}
</style>
<h2>My shop</h2>

<div id="product"><img src="assets/Product1.jpg" /><br /><input type="button" value="Buy" class="buy" id="Product1" />&nbsp;price:400$</div>
<div id="product"><img src="assets/Product2.jpg" /><br /><input type="button" value="Buy" class="buy" id="Product2"/>&nbsp;price:500$</div>
<div id="product"><img src="assets/Product3.jpg" /><br /><input type="button" value="Buy" class="buy" id="Product3" />&nbsp;price:600$</div><br />
<div id="shopping_cart" align="center">
<h1>Shopping cart</h1>
<hr />
    <div id="shopping_cart_items">
    </div>
 <hr />
 Sum:<div id="sum">0$</div>
</div>
```

I gave each product a unique num in order to delete it from the shopping cart, and i know i will probally need to use `.remove()`, but i tried many times in different ways  and couldn't get it right.

Comment: Since you're just appending text to a div, it's going to be very difficult to accomplish this without changing the existing code. Simply wrap each "product" in a container div, then to remove the product, remove the container div.

Comment: Also, fix your html, id's must be unique.

Comment: And for each product the div id should be unique in order for my to delete it right? and thank you for your help!

Comment: well, you don't really need id's to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/68yyr/

```
var sum = 0;
var num = 1;
//Assign the producets a price date
$("#Product1").data("price", 400);
$("#Product2").data("price", 500);
$("#Product3").data("price", 600);

//Adding the requested producted to the shopping cart
$(".buy").on("click", function (evt) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"),
        item = $('<div class="cart-item"></div>');
    item.append($(this).attr("id") + " " + "price: ");
    item.append($(this).data("price") + "$" + "<img src='assets/x.png' width='10px' height='10px' class='cancel' id=" + id + " + data-num= " + num++ + " data-price='" + $(this).data("price") + "' >" + "<br>");

    item.appendTo($("#shopping_cart_items"));

    //summing up the overall price
    sum = sum + $(this).data("price");
    $("#sum").text(sum + "$");
});

//Delete product from the shopping cart
$("#shopping_cart").on("click", ".cancel", function (evt) {
    var $this = $(evt.currentTarget),
        cartItem = $this.parent(),
        newPrice = parseInt($this.data('price'));

    cartItem.remove();
    sum = sum - newPrice;
    $("#sum").text(sum + "$");
});
```

Explanation of changes:

1. First of all, I'm not sure why you have the sum and num variables outside the jQuery closure.  This makes them global variables when they don't need to be, which is a bad practice.
2. Your '.cancel' event handler was nested within the '.buy' handler.  It should be on the same level.
3. You need to wrap each cart item in an element which will make it easier to select later.
4. The '.cancel' handler should be self explanatory.  It just removes the item and updates the total.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the shopping cart product in an element so you can remove it later.
Also, you have the delete code in the wrong place it have to be outside the buy `click` function>

See my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GBF7m/

```
var sum = 0;
var num = 1;
$(function () {
    //Assign the producets a price date
    $("#Product1").data("price", 400);
    $("#Product2").data("price", 500);
    $("#Product3").data("price", 600);

    //Adding the requested producted to the shopping cart
    $(".buy").on("click", function (evt) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("<span/>", {
            html: $(this).attr("id") + " " + "price: " + $(this).data("price") + "$" + "<img src='http://placehold.it/20x20' width='20px' height='20px' class='cancel' id=" + id + " + data-num= " + num+++" + ><br />",
                "data-price": $(this).data("price")
        }).appendTo("#shopping_cart_items");


        //summing up the overall price
        sum = sum + $(this).data("price");
        $("#sum").text(sum + "$");
    });

    //Delete product from the shopping cart
    $("#shopping_cart_items").on("click", ".cancel", function (evt) {
        $(this).parent("span").remove();
        sum = sum - $(this).parent("span").data("price");
        $("#sum").text(sum + "$");
    });
});
```